# Change state without refreshing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a home icon in the `navbar` whenever the user will click on it, It will take the user to the Home Page. In the Home Page, there are few form fields that I don't want to change when coming back to the Home Page from the navbar Home icon. The following is the code that I am using:

```
  back_to_home(){
    this.navCtrl.push( HomePage )
  }
```

By using the above, state is refreshed and changes. Is there way to change the state without refreshing the state?

Comment: The state of what changes? What do you mean refreshed? Do you just want to get rid of the animation?

Comment: You could store the content of the forms in the storage and use the `ionViewDidEnter` lifecycle event to initialize the forms again when the user opens the page again. If you want add the code of your forms and I could show you how to do it